# Calling makefile from subdirs

Tags: recursion, makefile

I have a structure of dirs with a couple of projects. Some of the projects depend on others ones which may in turn depend on others.

```
Dir
+-Proj1
| +-Debug
| |  makefile
| +-Release
|    makefile
|  <sources>
+-Proj2
| +-Debug
| |  makefile
| +-Release
|    makefile
|  <sources>
...
```

The `makefile`s automatically generated (by the Eclipse CDT) so I could not change it because in case of some changes in projects my changes will go away.

Now, every project must be built in the corresponding `Debug` or `Release` dirs. Each of the `makefile`s has a relative refers to the sources that's why I need to build every project in the `Debug` or `Release` dirs.

The `makefile`s which generated by the Eclipse contain a possibility to include a user makefiles. I use this feature to cause the `make` build projects which others depend on earlier. Suppose the Proj1 depends on the Proj2. Then I added dependency on the `../../Proj2/<Debug or Release>/proj2.so` for the result file of the Proj1 and added this rule for the Proj1:

```
$(USER_DEPS):                                  # (*)
    $(MAKE) -C "$(dir $@)" all
```

Here the `USER_DEPS` contains a list of a files which this project depends on. For example

```
USER_DEPS:=../../Proj2/Debug/proj2.so \
../../Proj3/Debug/proj3.so
```

And all of this works until I change something in the sources in the Proj2. Now if I run `make` for the Proj1 it see that the `../../Proj2/Debug/proj2.so` is here but it does not see that it is not actual. There could be ideal simply to include the `makefile` of the Proj2 into Proj1 instead of writing the rule marked with the `(*)`, but the `makefile` of the Proj2 contains a *relative* references to its sources. Ie if I will try to include them into Proj1 the `make` will try to find a Proj2's sources in the Proj1's dir.

Has someone any ideas?

Comment: I believe that's the kind of questions the next generation of build tools was invented for... Did you consider giving Gradle a shot ?

Comment: You could try `.PHONY:: $(USER_DEPS)`. But it may increase your build times, since it will always call the recursive make.

Comment: @MathiasDolidon, in short: no.